# usage of `else` in macros

Tags: c++, macros

I have seen the following code:

```
#define QL_REQUIRE(condition,message) \
if (!(condition)) { \
    std::ostringstream _ql_msg_stream; \
    _ql_msg_stream << message; \
    throw QuantLib::Error(__FILE__,__LINE__, \
                          BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION,_ql_msg_stream.str()); \
 } else
```

This is how we suppose to use it.

```
void testingMacros1 (){
   double x =0.0;
   QL_REQUIRE (x!=0 ," Zero number !");
}
```

I assume the `else` in the end has some special usage.

Question> What is the usage of `else` appended in the end of this macros definition?

Thank you

Comment: Look at the expanded usage of said macro. The C++ syntax has to be valid after the CPP; so looking at it in context should reveal the "why".

Comment: @pst, I have posted a usage of the macro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The macro checks the condition. It needs the condition to be `true`, or else it will throw an exception. If it's true, you'd put braces after like a normal `if` statement.

You'd use it like this:

```
QL_REQUIRE (x != 0, "x must not be 0")
{
    y = 100 / x; //dividing by 0 is bad
}
```

The macro subs in the condition, and if it fails, it will print the given message. If it doesn't fail, your braces or one-liner form the else statement. The logic is just a bit reversed when looking at the whole thing. When using it, it's like an `if`, but when subbing it in, the `if` and the `else` sort of get reversed roles.

It's sort of like saying this:

```
assert (x != 0 && "x must not be 0");
y = 100 / x; //dividing by 0 is bad
```

Comment: I have seen the idea behind the macro based on your answer. The macros `QL_REQUIRE` must be followed by a `;` or `{}` otherwise `else` itself will trigger a compilation error. `if(!condition) {} else;`.

Comment: @q0987, exactly like how an if statement must be followed by something as well. However, in both cases, if you forget to put in the body, you get strange logic due to the next line only executing under certain conditions.