# why we put else in the end of the macro

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac)

```
#define QL_REQUIRE(condition,message) \
if (!(condition)) { \
    std::ostringstream _ql_msg_stream; \
    _ql_msg_stream << message; \
    throw QuantLib::Error(__FILE__,__LINE__, \
                          BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION,_ql_msg_stream.str()); \
 } else
```

How to use it:

```
void testingMacros1 (){
   double x =0.0;
   QL_REQUIRE (x!=0 ," Zero number !");
}
```

why the macro injects a `else` in the end?

Comment: If you didn't, there'd be an extraneous semicolon, non?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac

Comment: Wrong dupe guys. I answered this exact question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744418/usage-of-else-in-macros/10744463#10744463).